Flutter - dependencies incompability of geolocator and firebase_auth
I'm trying to use two packages:

geolocator (version: 13.0.1) (https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)
firebase_auth (version: 5.2.0) (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)

I want to use the mentioned versions in my project, however I got the following error:
Resolving dependencies...
Because firebase_auth >=5.2.0 depends on firebase_auth_web ^5.12.6 which depends on web ^0.5.1, 
firebase_auth >=5.2.0 requires web ^0.5.1.
And because geolocator_web 4.1.1 depends on web ^1.0.0 and no versions of geolocator_web match >4.1.1 <5.0.0, 
firebase_auth >=5.2.0 is incompatible with geolocator_web ^4.1.1.
And because geolocator 13.0.1 depends on geolocator_web ^4.1.1 and no versions of geolocator match >13.0.1 <14.0.0, 
firebase_auth >=5.2.0 is incompatible with geolocator ^13.0.1.
So, because travel_mobile app depends on both geolocator ^13.0.1 and firebase_auth ^5.2.0, 
version solving failed.


You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
* Consider downgrading your constraint on firebase_auth: flutter pub add firebase_auth:^4.16.0

The problem is web package, because firebase_auth depends on web in the slightly depricated version - 0.5.1, and geolocator uses web in the newest version - 1.0.0
And indeed, downgrading the version of firebase_auth helps. But only due to the fact that firebase_auth:4.16.0 is the last version of firebase_auth that doesn't depend on the web package. (The dependency is indirect - through firebase_auth_web).
B.T.W To solve this riddle I researched dependencies of different versions on the firebase_auth github repository.)
And my question is: Is it possible to use the newest version of both packages for mobile only application?

You can use this:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocator: ^13.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^5.2.0

dependency_overrides:
  geolocator_web: 4.0.0

The dependency_overrides section in a pubspec.yaml file allows you to manually override the version constraints of specific dependencies for your Dart or Flutter project. This is useful when you want to resolve version conflicts or test with a different version of a package than the one that is being pulled in by default.
